# UiimageView adapted in a uiview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, scale, contentmode

I have a little problem with my UIImageView.
I want the content of UIImageView don't overflow to UIView.

When I tryed this code, I have this result, but I won't a image in area striped.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:view];

UIImageView *viewimageArticle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];
viewimageArticle.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"article1.jpeg"];
viewimageArticle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
viewimageArticle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
[view addSubview:viewimageArticle];
```

[image]

I tryed a many properties, "contentMode" and "autorezingMask" but i don't have good result.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

This causes its subviews to be clipped to the receivers bounds.

Answer (score 1):

set `clipsToBounds = YES` on view

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear of what you want to achieve, but what you want may be `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Also, you are creating the `UIImageView` frame in 300x100 first and resetting to 320x100. I believe the resetting part is not your intention.